# HTML5 exiting video fullscreen

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, html5-video

I have a *HTML5* video with custom controls in normal screen.
Don't have custom controls at full screen.
I just show default controls at full screen.
But when exiting full screen I need to disable default controls.
How do we know whether the video has exited the full screen mode using JavaScript or jQuery?

Answer (score 13):

You can only call `document.mozCancelFullScreen()`, if you’re inside a document which is *fullscreen*. i.e. if you’re in an which is a contained inside another document, which is *fullscreen*, mozCancelFullScreen() won’t do anything in the inner iframe, as only the outer document is acutally *fullscreen*. i.e. calling *mozCancelFullScreen* in the outer document will cancel *fullscreen*, but calling it in the inner document won’t.

Also be aware that `mozCancelFullScreen()` reverts *fullscreen* to have the previous *fullscreen* element as *fullscreen*. So if you’ve requested *fullscreen* multiple times, cancelling *fullscreen* won’t necessarily exit *fullscreen* fully, it may rollback to the previous *fullscreen* state.

**Examples:**

*1. You could go with:*

```
$(document).on('webkitExitFullScreen', function()      {       
  alert("Full Screen Closed"); 
});
```

*2. You could use a variable for further ussage:*

```
var exitedFullScreen;
$(document).on("webkitExitFullScreen", function() {
   exitedFullScreen = !!$(document).fullScreen();
}
```

*3. Applying it to your container:*

```
$('video')[0].webkitExitFullScreen();
```

*4. Using only JavaScript:*

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function ExitVideo() {
      document.getElementsByTagName('video')[0].webkitExitFullScreen();
  }
</script>
```

*5. There are also several third-party plugins which provide you access to the event you need:*

- http://johndyer.name/native-fullscreen-javascript-api-plus-jquery-plugin/
- https://github.com/ruidlopes/jquery-fullscreen

**EDIT 1**

There are compatibility issue across browsers, here is the example of different statements:

```
document.webkitExitFullscreen();
document.mozCancelFullscreen();
document.exitFullscreen();
```

#### EDIT 2

The Fullscreen API is enabled by default in *Chrome 15*, *Firefox 14*, and *Opera 12*. For more information on the rest of the API, see the spec.

> Updated 2012-10-11: to be inline with spec changes. Lowercased the "S"
>   in requestFullscreen() and changed document.webkitCancelFullScreen()
>   to document.webkitExitFullscreen().

#### EDIT 3

Try the following, without using jQuery to debug in Firefox:

```
var videoElement = document.getElementById("myvideo");

  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      toggleFullScreen();
    }
  }, false);
```

#### EDIT 4

For using with jQuery in Firefox, try the different example:

```
if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) { 
    alert('Full Screen Closed') 
}
```

Comment: Thanks but the first block you wrote here is not working.
Im using mozilla firefox 24.0. Does it have any browser compatibility issue

Comment: I used like this, but alert is not showig 

$(document).on('mozCancelFullscreen', function()      {       
  alert("Full Screen Closed"); 
});

Comment: Did you try it in other browsers?

Comment: the last one is ok, that is on enter key press.. but we need it on the mouse cliking on the exitfull screen icon.

Comment: Bind it to the mouse event on that element, by id for example?

Comment: I got to go now! If my question not good for you and you need more help - I will come back later, in the evening.

Comment: We cant get that icon as it is default control. when we inspect it it is shown as <video> element. so cant bind to that :)

Comment: How about binding it to esc keypress? Or you needed it for mouse clicks? Are you using particular video player?

Comment: HTML5 video can exit/enter full screen by 'double cliking' or by cliking the fullscreen/normal screen icon, also can exit full screen by escape key.
So we can't do a code related to a particular button clik or mouse clik. Just need to know if any event raises when the player exits full screen

Comment: I see.. I think the event raises for sure but I personally haven't yet encountered this kind of problem personally. I would recommend getting open-source video player, like *video-js* and look through its code.

Answer (score 8):

Here is an updated code as for now (Jun 4th 2017), works on all browsers:

```
if (document.exitFullscreen)
    document.exitFullscreen();
else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen)
    document.webkitExitFullscreen();
else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen)
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
else if (document.msExitFullscreen)
    document.msExitFullscreen();
```

Answer (score 7):

I took this from the post above but added onto It. I set the document values which then allowed me to exit fullscreen.

```
  var videoElement = document.getElementById("myvideo");

  function toggleFullScreen() {
    if (!document.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
      if (videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        videoElement.mozRequestFullScreen();
      } else {
        videoElement.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
      }
      document.mozFullScreen = true;
      document.webkitFullScreen = true;
    } else {
      if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
        document.mozCancelFullScreen();
      } else {
        document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
      }
    }
  }

  document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      toggleFullScreen();
    }
  }, false);
```

I only added these two lines ..

> document.mozFullScreen = true;
>
> document.webkitFullScreen = true;

which worked perfect for me in addition to llia's code above.

**Edit: This Seems like a better fix then what was written before.**

```
  fullScreenButton.addEventListener("click", function() {
   if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
   !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
     if (video.requestFullscreen) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
     } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      video.msRequestFullscreen();
     } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      video.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
     }
    } else {
     if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
     } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
     } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
     } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
      document.webkitExitFullscreen();
     }
    }
   });
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('video').bind('webkitfullscreenchange mozfullscreenchange fullscreenchange', function(e) {
    var state = document.fullScreen || document.mozFullScreen || document.webkitIsFullScreen;
    var event = state ? 'FullscreenOn' : 'FullscreenOff';

    // Now do something interesting
    alert('Event: ' + event);    
});
```

Comment: List your sources if you're going to copy/paste: http://www.intheloftstudios.com/blog/detecting-html5-video-fullscreen-and-events