# Adding an X to upper right hand corner of HTML5 fullscreen video

Tags: javascript, html, video

I'm designing a website with a video banner that, upon pressing play, opens a video using an HTML5 player on fullscreen. Here's the JavaScript that is called when the play button is pressed.

```
function addVideo() {
    var video = $(document).find('#intro-video')[0]; // find the newly inserterd video
    video.src = "../../assets/images/intro.mp4";
    video.controls = false;
    video.load();
    video.play();
    goFullscreen(video);
}

function goFullscreen(myVideo) {
    if (myVideo.requestFullscreen) {
        myVideo.requestFullscreen();
    } else if (myVideo.msRequestFullscreen) {
        myVideo.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else if (myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen) {
        myVideo.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (myVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
        myVideo.webkitRequestFullScreen();
    }
}
```

I'd like to put an X in the upper right hand corner of the video that, when clicked, simulates pressing the escape key or calls a JavaScript method. Can someone give me an example of that being done?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357854/html5-exiting-video-fullscreen

Comment: Thanks for the link. However, I already have a JS method to exit full screen. I want to add an X to the upper right hand corner that calls my method to close it when clicked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did something similar a while ago, I ended up making a div container fullScreen instead of the video tag, and had the video at 100% width and height on that div,
then you can position other elements inside the div, just use position: absolute/relative on the container and overlayed items