# function exitFullscreen not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery, video, fullscreen

I am pretty new to javascript and I am building a play video in fullscreen function with the Fullscreen API.

In my app i am trying to trigger a css change in the video div when the user exits fullscreen mode, but it doesn't seem to work. My guess is that I have called the else statement wrong, but I am unsure where it is wrong. Would greatly appreciate some help :)

Code is pasted below

HTML

```
<div id="film">
<video class="video_player" id="player" width="20%" controls="controls" muted >
<source src="/testmovie.mp4"/>
</video>
</div>

<button id="fullscreenFilm" onclick="goFullscreen('player'); playVid();">
PLAY FILM
</button>
```

CSS

```
#film {
display:none;
}
```

JS

```
var vid = document.getElementById('player'); 
var container = document.getElementById('film'); 

function goFullscreen(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);   

if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
element.mozRequestFullScreen();

} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}  

else {
if (element.exitFullscreen) {
  element.exitFullscreen();
  container.style.display = "none";
  }
 }

}


function playVid() { 

container.style.display = "block";
vid.play(); 
vid.currentTime = 0; 

}
```

## **EDIT 1**

I tried this new method to detect when the fullscreen is closed, but the display:none still doesn't work correctly.

```
function goFullscreen(id) {
var element = document.getElementById(id);   

if (element.mozRequestFullScreen) {
element.mozRequestFullScreen();

} else if (element.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
element.webkitRequestFullScreen();
}  

}



function toggleFullScreen() {
if (!vid.mozFullScreen && !document.webkitFullScreen) {
  if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
  } else {
    vid.webkitRequestFullScreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
  }
  document.mozFullScreen = true;
  document.webkitFullScreen = true;
  } else {
  if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
    document.mozCancelFullScreen();
  } else {
    document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
  }
  }
  }


 document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
 if (e.keyCode == 13) {
  toggleFullScreen();
  container.style.display = "none";
  }
  }, false);




 function playVid() { 

container.style.display = "block";
vid.play(); 
vid.currentTime = 0; 

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your function goFullscreen('player') only fires on click here and is not fired again when they exit full screen. I'd recommend adding another function exitFullscreen() that you add as an eventListner to when they exit full screen and have that function handle your logic. A much more detailed answer has already been written here on how to handle this [HTML5 exiting video fullscreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19357854/html5-exiting-video-fullscreen) you would just want to add your changes to the css inside of their call back function using their example:

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
      toggleFullScreen();
      container.style.display = "none";
    }
  }, false);
```

I should note I used their an example to show that there was two different events taking place that you will need to account for. In the link they posted a single click event listener that you can add to the video that will handle everything for you that you just need to add. So on every-click event it does the checks. With your current code it only does your checks when you click the button not on the video

Stolen from before mentioned post with an edit:

```
document.getElementById('player').addEventListener("click", function() {
   if (!document.fullscreenElement &&    // alternative standard method
   !document.mozFullScreenElement && !document.webkitFullscreenElement && !document.msFullscreenElement ) {  // current working methods
     if (video.requestFullscreen) {
      video.requestFullscreen();
     } else if (video.msRequestFullscreen) {
      video.msRequestFullscreen();
     } else if (video.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      video.mozRequestFullScreen();
     } else if (video.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      video.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
     }
    } else {
     //This is now where you would want to revent back to the display none
         container.style.display = "none";
         if (document.exitFullscreen) {
          document.exitFullscreen();
         } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
          document.msExitFullscreen();
         } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
          document.mozCancelFullScreen();
         } else if (document.webkitExitFullscreen) {
          document.webkitExitFullscreen();
         }
        }
       });
```

Comment: Oh i see, thank you for your very well explained answer! Hmm i tried adding it but does not seem to work - i am not sure if I have missed something or missunderstood.

(check my new edit)

Comment: I don't see the new code.

But for reference you add listner events like

document.getElementById('player').addEventListener('click', function)

Comment: Ok yeah sorry, I didn't intend for you to directly use that code. It was more anexample of how to add an eventlistner

Comment: I added  the event listener to my post from the example i mention that should work for click events on the video element.

Comment: I updated my post to show how you can add an event listner on the element with id=player . The event listens for click events. So when the player is now clicked everytime it should run this to handle your cases.

Comment: Okey thanks! I tried this with multiple ways, which none of them work.

1. Adding the code to my existing code, didn't work :/

2. Removing my function goFullscreen, as these two codes bascially do the same thing, replacing the eventListener to the button, but then the function playVid function won't function. Without replacing the eventListener to the button, it won't trigger the video itself.