# HTML5 Video onStart Fullscreen

Tags: javascript, css, html, popcornjs

Is it possible to set a video to full screen on page load?

So far, the only answer I could get to work and was actually logical to me was setting the width and height on the element via CSS.

```js
var $pop = Popcorn("#video");
$pop.play();
console.dir( $pop )
```

```css
html{font-family:arial;}
#video{width:100%;height:100%;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

<video height="180" width="300" id="video" controls> 
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.mp4"></source>
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv"></source>
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.webm"></source>
</video>
```

I use Popcorn.js for playing the video on startup.

I am aware of setting CSS classes from JavaScript. The thing I'm more interested in would be the question: is there is a JavaScript based method to call, to maximize the video to full screen (on startup).

Using JavaScript, as suggested by Will, I also can't seem to get it to work properly

```js
var video = $("#video");
var vid = video[0];
vid.play();
if (vid.requestFullscreen) {
    vid.requestFullscreen();
} else if (vid.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    vid.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (vid.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
    vid.webkitRequestFullscreen();
}
```

```css
html{font-family:arial;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://popcornjs.org/code/dist/popcorn-complete.min.js"></script>

<video height="180" width="300" id="video" controls> 
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.mp4"></source>
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.ogv"></source>
<source src="http://videos.mozilla.org/serv/webmademovies/popcornplug.webm"></source>
</video>
```

Comment: you can try something like this http://www.codesynthesis.co.uk/tutorials/html-5-full-screen-and-responsive-videos

Comment: Or this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106131/request-full-screen-html5-video-onplay

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055214/is-there-a-way-to-make-html5-video-fullscreen  also, it has to be full screen or can be full page? Inside the page is possible.

Comment: if you mean you'd like the browser to go into fullscreen mode (F11) upon visiting your page, you could possibly hack this action but browsers would fight you - i'd be surprised if this wasnt specifically prohibited in the specs - and users would probably hate you too, it'd be awful for the user to immediately have their screen commandeered by your web page. Recommend against this action.
If you are after video in the viewport (the entire page within the browser window) then this is easily done:
https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#safe=off&q=fullscreen%2Bhtml5%2Bvideo%2Bexample

Comment: Sorry, wanted to write more.
@Anonymous
I did research and found one possible WORKING solution, which was posted in the original question. Problem being that it only filled the *Page* not the *Screen*.

DhirajBodicherla and Elric posted the solution I used in the fiddle

Will was helpful, I edited my post using the resources from his link.

Comment: @MichaM. My mistake. I saw the infamous "I did research" in your post and assumed you were just stating that as fact. I would suggest never mentioning that as it should be obvious from the post already and just adds fluff to the post. Also, I would suggest spell checking, using stack snippets instead of a fiddle, and not saying "**edit**" since all edits can be found in the edit history. I have made these changes, but feel free to change anything you don't like. :)

Comment: Was not aware of this feature, ty very much @Anonymous

Comment: This might be of interest http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9454125/javascript-request-fullscreen-is-unreliable