# vimeo player custom player on IOS has fullscreen button

Tags: javascript, video, html5-video, vimeo

In vimeo player, example page:
https://vimeo.com/4378389

the player works great with their custom player on my iphone (IOS 12)

and they even have a fullscreen button that works!

I tried everything with fullScreen API but nothing works
My code:
(this happens on user click event)

```
if (vidObj.requestFullscreen) {
    vidObj.requestFullscreen();
} else if (vidObj.mozRequestFullScreen) {
    vidObj.mozRequestFullScreen();
} else if (vidObj.webkitRequestFullScreen) {
    vidObj.webkitRequestFullScreen();
} else if (vidObj.msRequestFullscreen) {
    vidObj.msRequestFullscreen();
}
```

Any ideas about what they are doing?

Thanks

Comment: Vimeo embeds work different than the on-site experience. What does your iframe embed code look like? Are you using the "playsinline" parameter in the embed code? https://vimeo.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000636368-Inline-Playback-on-Mobile

Comment: Is this inside a user triggered event? For security and good user experience, browsers will only let you trigger full screen inside a user-triggered event, like a 'click' - from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17106131/request-full-screen-html5-video-onplay

Comment: @TommyPenner Im building my own player, vimeo is just an example. But yes Im using "playsinline" in my player.

Comment: @LukeGedeon yes this is inside an on click event of course, adding that.